# not able to install boost library for c++ in windows

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, boost

I am trying to install boost library for c++ in windows. I am using a GCC compiler. I searched for it on the internet but everywhere the only installation of boost library in visual studio is given. 
I found somewhere to go to boost/tools/build and then to run bootstrap.sh, but the following error is being shown:

```
C:\Program Files\boost_1_73_0\tools\build>bootstrap.sh The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: .sh is Linux shell script, find .bat file and try to run if it is there

Answer (score 0):

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#install-boost-build

here is instruction to install boost on windows. File you want to open is shell script (probably taken from Linux instructions), which generally should not be called on Windows. Use bootstrap.bat instead.

Comment: b2 engine is not able to be built on executing 'bootstrap.bat' command. This error is being shown  :        

Failed to build the B2 engine. What should I do now?